# setOnKeyListener in fragment not listening

Tags: android

Is there something I'm missing in this code?
Yes, I know this is mostly code, but IMHO I think it is clear.
Stil there seems to be more unnecessary text needed.

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    if(container == null) { return null; }
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) outsideLayout.findViewById(R.id.prefPlayerName);
        editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT); 
        editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO);

        editText.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
            {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" key
                if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
                {
                    Log.i(TAG, "PrefDetailsFragment enter key pressed");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    return outsideLayout;
}   // onCreateView()
```

Comment: Where is outsideLayout coming from?

Comment: IMHO the first two lines in this method are totally useless ... The first line should inflate the view from an XML, or at least create the view somehow. This is the sole purpose of `onCreateView`: to create and instantiate the UI.

Comment: @Jon, I created this earlier, but within onCreateView(). Otherwise notting else will work in this fragment.

Comment: @PageMaker earlier as in a previous instance? You'll need to include more information about that as it's key to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Jon, you could replace "outsideLayout" with container.  That's not the issue.  The point is that ...setOnkeyListener does not give the expected log output; so I suspect that it is not working at all. I have some of this unexpected behaviour earlier when working within onCreateView() within a fragment.

Answer (score -1):

Try moving `editText` outside of `onCreateView` and setting the listener in `onResume` as well. You may also want to remove the call to the super and to exit when the container is null.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if ( editText != null && ! editTexthasOnClickListeners() ) {
        editText.setOnKeyListener( ... );   // Add on click listener here as well
    }
}
```